# Can you help me stop getting crash errors in my pc with MS-Access?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to run a query in access and I keep getting an error message stopping me from running it. Is the query too big or, is my computer too slow? It is a very old computer so I think that is the most likely scenario, also it's dell.  The query works when I am not selecting DISTINCT but won't when I do. However, I get too many repeats so I need DISTINCT.

## SQL Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ECOG 2809 ICORG 11-04].Title, 
  [Anti-Mullerian AMH_SVU_1].Name, 
  [Tarceva Biomarker ICORG 11-21].Name, 
  [Pfizer Archer].Name, 
  [Collaborative Biomarker Study].Name, 
  [MYOCET ICORG 10-03].Name, 
  [doVe Electro-Chemo].[First name], 
  [Spinal Compression].Title, 
  SNP.Title, SNP.[First Name], 
  [PET -CT LUNG 06-35].[First Name], 
  CharactHer.[First Name], 
  [Perfosine Myslemo].[First Name], 
  SWOG_1.Name, 
  [Phase 2].[First Name], 
  SIVUH.Name, 
  SLRON.Name, 
  [Spinal Cord Retreat].[First name], 
  [doVe Electro-Chemo].[First name], 
  [Circulating miRNAs ICORG 10-11].[First Name], 
  Endomentrial.Title, 
  [Pfizer Archer].Name, 
  [IMRT Prostate].[First name], 
  Glioma.[First name], 
  [Genito Urinary].[First name], 
  [GSK VEG113387 ICORG 11-05].[First name]
FROM [TH v THL], 
  [Tarceva Biomarker ICORG 11-21], 
  SWOG, 
  SWOG AS SWOG_1, 
  [Spinal Cord Retreat], 
  [Spinal Compression], 
  SNP, 
  SLRON, 
  [Phase 2], 
  SIVUH, 
  [Pfizer Archer], 
  [PET -CT LUNG 06-35], 
  [Perfosine Myslemo], 
  [MYOCET ICORG 10-03], 
  [IMRT Prostate], 
  [GSK VEG113387 ICORG 11-05], 
  Glioma, 
  [Genito Urinary], 
  Endomentrial, 
  [ECOG 2809 ICORG 11-04], 
  [doVe Electro-Chemo], 
  [Collaborative Biomarker Study], 
  [Circulating miRNAs ICORG 10-11], 
  CharactHer, 
  [Biomarkers of Response Taxotere], 
  ANZGOG, 
  [Anti-Mullerian AMH_SVU], 
  [Anti-Mullerian AMH_SVU] AS [Anti-Mullerian AMH_SVU_1]
WHERE 
(
  (
    ([ECOG 2809 ICORG 11-04].Title) Is Null 
      Or ([ECOG 2809 ICORG 11-04].Title) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([Anti-Mullerian AMH_SVU_1].Name) Is Null 
      Or ([Anti-Mullerian AMH_SVU_1].Name) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([Tarceva Biomarker ICORG 11-21].Name) Is Null 
      Or ([Tarceva Biomarker ICORG 11-21].Name) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([Pfizer Archer].Name) Is Null
      Or ([Pfizer Archer].Name) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([Collaborative Biomarker Study].Name) Is Null 
      Or ([Collaborative Biomarker Study].Name) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([MYOCET ICORG 10-03].Name) Is Null 
      Or ([MYOCET ICORG 10-03].Name) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([doVe Electro-Chemo].[First name]) Is Null 
      Or ([doVe Electro-Chemo].[First name]) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([Spinal Compression].Title) Is Null 
      Or ([Spinal Compression].Title) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    (SNP.Title) Is Null 
      Or (SNP.Title) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    (SNP.[First Name]) Is Null 
      Or (SNP.[First Name]) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([PET -CT LUNG 06-35].[First Name]) Is Null 
      Or ([PET -CT LUNG 06-35].[First Name]) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    (CharactHer.[First Name]) Is Null 
      Or (CharactHer.[First Name]) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([Perfosine Myslemo].[First Name]) Is Null 
      Or ([Perfosine Myslemo].[First Name]) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    (SWOG_1.Name) Is Null 
      Or (SWOG_1.Name) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([Phase 2].[First Name]) Is Null 
      Or ([Phase 2].[First Name]) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    (SIVUH.Name) Is Null 
      Or (SIVUH.Name) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    (SLRON.Name) Is Null 
      Or (SLRON.Name) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([Spinal Cord Retreat].[First name]) Is Null 
      Or ([Spinal Cord Retreat].[First name]) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([doVe Electro-Chemo].[First name]) Is Null 
      Or ([doVe Electro-Chemo].[First name]) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([Circulating miRNAs ICORG 10-11].[First Name]) Is Null 
      Or ([Circulating miRNAs ICORG 10-11].[First Name]) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    (Endomentrial.Title) Is Null 
      Or (Endomentrial.Title) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([Pfizer Archer].Name) Is Null 
      Or ([Pfizer Archer].Name) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([IMRT Prostate].[First name]) Is Null 
      Or ([IMRT Prostate].[First name]) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    (Glioma.[First name]) Is Null 
      Or (Glioma.[First name]) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([Genito Urinary].[First name]) Is Null 
      Or ([Genito Urinary].[First name]) Between "A" And "G"
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    ([GSK VEG113387 ICORG 11-05].[First name]) Is Null 
      Or ([GSK VEG113387 ICORG 11-05].[First name]) Between "A" And "G")
);
```

## Error message

> The query cannot be completed. Either the size of the query result is larger than the maximum size of a database (2GB) or there is not enough temporary storage space on the disk to store the query result

Comment: You query contains nearly 30 tables and not one join between them? That is going to produce one hell of a Cartesian product.

Comment: A few things, do you realize that you are creating a cartesian result for 28 tables?  You are multiplying the rows in each table by the rows in EVERY OTHER TABLE!!  Is that really what you want to do?  My suggestion would be to reconsider this query, look at joining them.

Comment: OP states that w/o `DISTINCT` s/he is OK. So apparently the existing environment can sustain the monster result set by itself.  It seems more likely that there's not enough space for temporary storage that `DISTINCT` requires.

Comment: @bluefeet is completely right you are pretty much going to want to blow this query away and start from scratch

Comment: even though that is likely true, the OP needs to resolve the Cartesian product / bad joins so the `DISTINCT` doesn't require so much storage to manage extraneous rows.

Comment: You don't need the distinct you need `INNER JOINS`!

Comment: this is not an answer. this is a comment. however, this comment is closer to the truth than the comment to defrag the hard drive, though.

Comment: @PM77-1 that's a joke right?

Comment: yeah this is what happens when I let Access do the SQL for me. Looks like Ill just code it myself with INNER JOINS. Thanks guys. Ill update you on whether it works or not.

Comment: Can someone point me in the right direction for changing this into INNER JOINS? I thought I knew how to change it, turns out I dont. Like even show me how to do the first line, thats all I would need. Thanks for the help anyway guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) when you make your queries in the Access query designer, you have to draw a line between the tables to join them by Primary Key. Which, I'm guessing you can't go, because ...

(2) The way the data are imported does not make sense for a database schema. On the one hand, they way it is (one study per table with I'm guessing a "Name" field) is so far away from a properly designed database as to be useless.

For example, 30+ tables like this:

- table names=[the name of the study]
  tables named by a specific data item are a dead giveaway that the design is wrong. you should be able to enter new data without changing the table structure. Therefore, *database tables are more aptly named after the kind of data that are in them*
- table contains: Pt. name, (other stuff). That's OK.

(3) On the other hand, the way it should be is very simple. You would not need any joins.

- One table called StudyParticipants.
- 2+ fields: StudyName, Pt_Name, (Other fields)
- [if you get into programming actually you'd have other tables, e.g., 'studies', etc.]

(4) I'm guessing that the design is as such not because you wanted it that way, but because that's just the way the import put it. You probably had a spreadsheet with a tab per study. I can also tell because the first name field is slightly different.

That's not going to work if you want to use a database. You'd be better off writing a macro to loop thru your excel sheet.

(5) If you want to import it right, you'll have to create one table first, with columns that match all the possible columns on any sheet. Then you'll have to import the sheets one at a time, each time that occurs, for the StudyName field of the database for the entire sheet matching the tabname of the sheet in your workbook.

A sad prognosis, it's true.

Before you go doing all this, of course, you could create a query where you try to UNION them all into one big table (renaming the diverse name fields into one using the AS clause), and then run a query on the union'd view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and before I do anything if I UNIONed all of the tables into one big table would that cause it to run much slower or would that make a difference?

Comment: If all the tables are of the same "type" (e.g. they all have same number of columns and the respecting columns are of same datatype), then a `UNION` query would be the way to go - and much, very much more efficient than the huge cross join you have.

Comment: Thank you I did the union like SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM (

 SELECT Title AS Name FROM [ECOG 2809 ICORG 11-04]
  UNION 
   SELECT Name FROM [Anti-Mullerian AMH_SVU_1]
    UNION 
   SELECT Name FROM [Tarceva Biomarker ICORG 11-21]
    UNION  and it looks like it will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Too big for a comment:

I'm struggling to find the meaning of results that *seem* like they'd return as this:

```
[ECOG 2809 ICORG 11-04].Title   [Anti-Mullerian AMH_SVU_1].Name [Tarceva Biomarker ICORG 11-21].Name    ...
-----------------------------   ------------------------------- ------------------------------------
null                            null                            null
A                               null                            null
A                               A                               null
...
G                               G                               F
G                               G                               G
```

Nothing seems related.

Can you possibly show us a table schema, some example data, and desired output?  You might have to make up the data considering the names of your tables and columns.  I wonder if your data was imported into Access in a non-sensical manner?

Comment: It was imported from an excel table and yeah Ill give you some example data. It is a bit personal so I'll have to through together a few fake details and upload it here. Thanks for the help.